# Can you use { instead of [ in json for a list of Json Objects

Tags: json, list

I am building my own Json and I was just wondering if you could make a list of Json objects like this "familyList":{} instead of "familyList":[ {}, {}, {}] because in the one with the '{' instead  of the usual '[' you can put a key next to the {} like "Mother":{} which will be easier for me to sort through since I will be having a lot of data instead of having to open multiple brackets like this: {}, {}, {}. I am relatively new to JSON so an answer would be greatly appreciated :) !

Comment: If you use `{ }` then it's not a list, it's an object.

Comment: Short answer: "No". Lists are `[...]`, objects are `{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
familyList = {{}, {}, {}};
```

I do not believe that is valid json. Perhaps, the below is what you are looking for.

```
familyList = {"Mother": {}, "Father": {} }
```

Maybe there is something in this link that could help: [enter link description here](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/04/json-tutorial/)

Comment: Ye I would like to do something like familyList = {"Mother": {}, "Father": {} }, is that possible?

Comment: Yes that is very possible